# MySQL help regarding AND AND OR

Tags: php, mysql

Some quick help.. What I want to do is this:

If 'X' greater or equal to 100 and user logged on, do "the code", but only if user_id is 1 or 2.

Is the code below representing that? I am unsure because of the OR.. Does the OR apply to the last AND or to the complete query? How could I simplify/correct the code?

```
if($data['x'] >= 100 AND $_SESSION['user_logged'] = 1 AND $data['user_id']
== 1 OR $data['user_id'] == 2)
```

Comment: Your title and question is being little distracting. You're asking solution for `MySQL` and showing code of `PHP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(
($data['x'] >= 100  
  AND $_SESSION['user_logged'] ==1 ) 
  AND ($data['user_id']== 1 || $data['user_id'] == 2))
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: why was this suddenly downvoted? just curious to know.

Answer (score 2):

This part of your code `AND $_SESSION['user_logged'] = 1`

You're assigning using one equal sign, instead of comparing using two (or three).

So do:

```
AND $_SESSION['user_logged'] == 1
```

and make sure you've started the session. Meaning that `session_start();` is inside (all) your page(s) using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Sidenote: `&&` has precedence over `AND`, as does `||` over `OR`.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 1):

You had an error in your `if` statement where you were assigning the value of `$_SESSION['user_logged']` to 1. I fixed that in your code and I also wrapped your `AND` statements in parenthesis as you are requiring either the first three conditions be met OR the last condition be met and to achieve that you want to use parenthesis

```
if(
    ($data['x'] >= 100
    AND $_SESSION['user_logged'] == 1
    AND $data['user_id'] == 1)
    OR $data['user_id'] == 2
)
```